# Not displaying selected values from form Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a sample flask application which I developed using WTForms from various sources. My main intention is to in the first place is to see whether all options work properly so I developed the app in such a way that the selected options are displayed again.

The app is publicly avalaible [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=78222551968311514674). However, the app doesn't work as expected. Can anybody help me fix this? This is my routes.py file as follows:

```
# Import the actual Flask app
from app import app

from flask import render_template, redirect, jsonify, request, url_for
import sys
import os

from forms import PlagSelection


@app.route('/')# methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def select_doc():
    form = PlagSelection()

    # If file has been selected, perform detection and display results
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        kwargs = {
            form.features.name : form.features.data,
            form.cluster_method.name : form.cluster_method.data,
            form.atom.name : form.atom.data,
            form.similarity_measure.name : form.similarity_measure.data,
            form.k.name : form.k.data
        }
        print kwargs
        return redirect(url_for('view_doc', **kwargs))
    elif len(form.errors) > 0:
        # TODO Make a nice error msg
        return str(form.errors)
    else:
        # Otherwise display options
        return render_template('select_doc.html',
                    form = form)

@app.route('/view_doc/',methods=['GET'])
def view_doc():
    atom_type = request.args.get('atom')
    features = request.args.getlist('features')
    cluster_method = request.args.get('cluster_method')
    similarity_measure = request.args.get('similarity_measure')
    k = int(request.args.get('k'))

    return render_template('view_doc.html',
        cluster_method = cluster_method,
        k = k,
        features = features,
        atom_type = atom_type,
        similarity_measure = similarity_measure
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(debug = True, port=port)
```

My html file is as follows:

```
<html>


{% block content %}

<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Pick your plag</h1>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <dt>
            <form method="POST" action='/view_doc' enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <dd> {{ form.features.label }} </dd>
                    <dd> {{ form.features(class='form-control') }} </dd>

                    <dd> {{ form.atom.label }} </dd>
                    <dd> {{ form.atom(class='form-control') }} </dd>

                    <dd> {{ form.cluster_method.label }} </dd>
                    <dd> {{ form.cluster_method(class='form-control') }} </dd>

                    <dd> {{ form.k.label }} </dd>
                    <dd> {{ form.k(class='form-control') }} </dd>

                    <dd> {{ form.similarity_measure.label }} </dd>
                    <dd> {{ form.similarity_measure(class='form-control') }} </dd>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Go </button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </dt>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
{% endblock content %}

</html>
```

I get the following error:
[image]

** EDIT **

I changed the routs.py as follows:

```
# Import the actual Flask app
from app import app

from flask import render_template, redirect, jsonify, request, url_for, session
import sys
import os

from forms import PlagSelection


@app.route('/')# methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def select_doc():
    form = PlagSelection()

    # If file has been selected, perform detection and display results
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['form_data']= {
            form.features.name : form.features.data,
            form.cluster_method.name : form.cluster_method.data,
            form.atom.name : form.atom.data,
            form.similarity_measure.name : form.similarity_measure.data,
            form.k.name : form.k.data
        }
        return redirect(url_for('view_doc'))
    elif len(form.errors) > 0:
        # TODO Make a nice error msg
        return str(form.errors)
    else:
        # Otherwise display options
        return render_template('select_doc.html',
                    form = form)

@app.route('/view_doc',methods=['POST'])
def view_doc():
    atom_type = session.get('atom')
    features = session.get('features')
    cluster_method = session.get('cluster_method')
    similarity_measure = session.get('similarity_measure')
    k = int(session.get('k'))

    return render_template('view_doc.html',
        cluster_method = cluster_method,
        k = k,
        features = features,
        atom_type = atom_type,
        similarity_measure = similarity_measure
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(debug = True, port=port)
```

I get the error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/plag/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/plag/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/plag/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/plag/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/plag/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/plag/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/plag/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/plag/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/eadaradhiraj/Documents/plag/samp_app/app/routes.py", line 39, in view_doc
    k = int(session.get('k'))
```

Comment: You need to provide a minimal set of code that reproduces the problems you are having. As it stands, your question is not well suited for SO. If you are having a particular issue that you are trying to debug, you should post some details. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You need to provide the MVCE here. URLs change. Links expire. Please read the help article shared by @wgwz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not quite an MCVE but I notice two things.

Try changing `'/view_doc/'` to `'/view_doc'`. Unless you have a particular reason for using the trailing slash.

The other thing is `return redirect(url_for('view_doc', **kwargs))`. I think that is where the 'POST-request' portion of the error is coming from. Based off the error it seems that its not safe to pass the data this way.

Try using `session` instead for holding the form data and removing the use of `**kwargs`.

```
session['my_form_data'] = {
        form.features.name : form.features.data,
        form.cluster_method.name : form.cluster_method.data,
        form.atom.name : form.atom.data,
        form.similarity_measure.name : form.similarity_measure.data,
        form.k.name : form.k.data
    }

return redirect(url_for('view_doc'))
```

In `'/view_doc'` you can access the form data as `session.get('atom')`, etc.

Comment: Hi, I tried but I get another error. Please check the edit.

Comment: Post the *full traceback* but before you do that, make sure that all the `session.get` lines are returning the correct values. Test it with print statements, e.g. `print session.get('atom')`. Also comment out the lines that are troublesome (according to the traceback). This is what happens without an MCVE, your post becomes huge and you need to continually edit and add tracebacks. Which is not good for posterity. Also writing up an MCVE is IMO a nice way to debug code.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the reply. On what basis do you specify the key for session?

Comment: `session['my_form_data']` is my_form_data arbitrary?

Comment: Yup. The keys can be anything.